# Which ruby version am I using?

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure what Ruby version is being used on my device (macOS) by default.

`ruby -v` outputs `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]`

`brew list ruby --versions` outputs `ruby 3.0.2`

`rbenv versions` outputs

```
  system
* 2.7.4 (set by /Users/nlakritz/.rbenv/version)
```

Comment: `rbenv` shows the version(s) managed by _rbenv_. `ruby --version` shows the version of the ruby in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ruby -v` shows 2.6.3, then you are using the ruby which ships with the system by default.  You can confirm this in several ways.  Running the shell command `which ruby` will show `/usr/bin/ruby`.  Checking your `PATH` will show `/usr/bin` earlier than the location of the homebrew or rbenv installations.

If you wish to run one of the others, you can put it earlier on the `PATH` or invoke it explicitly by giving the fully qualified name such as `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby myscript.rb`.  Another alternative which avoids twiddling the `PATH` variable is to use a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning of different scripts pointing explicitly to the version to use with that script.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'default'. If you're running a file with `ruby filename` then the version you are using is 2.6 (because you're running the same Ruby as `ruby --version`).

If you're running a file directly (eg. `./filename.rb`) then it depends on the shebang line in the file. For example, the file could start with the line `#!/usr/bin/ruby`, so to check which version of ruby that file is running on, you could call `/usr/bin/ruby --version`.

Hopefully that helps, but I'm not 100% sure I understood what you're asking - so let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.7.0"
```

So, rbenv is ignored, I think you're missing this in your path:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
ruby -v # should say 2.7 now
```

And if it says 2.7, you can add the export and eval commands at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` to load it every time you open a shell, thus kicking off rbenv override.

I would bet 2.6 for you, ie `ruby -v`.

Comment: `irb` and `ruby` are distinct commands.  It's possible to have multiple versions of each.

Comment: yes they're two commands, but is there a situation where `irb` wouldn't be running the same ruby? - just learning something here.

Comment: It's unlikely, but somebody could have linked to one of them earlier on the path and neglected to clean that up on a later install.  I've seen seen colleagues do weirder things than that.  The `which` command would be a more reliable indicator of which version is actually being used when you type the command.